# Seemingly basic MongoDB GridFS commands...that I cannot find

Tags: gridfs, mongodb

How, through the mongo shell, do I "upload" a file to my MongoDB and how to I retrieve that same file? I wonder, what is the output, even, after doing so.

I think showing what I've done will show how foolish my attempts have been.

```
db.fs.files.insert("foo.txt");
```

This just seems to insert the actual text not the document I want...and to retrieve, I found that

```
db.fs.files.retrieve()
```

Isnt a function. find() just displays to me...but I want the actual document's contents printed, whether it be BINARY data or w/e I don't care, haha.

I'm sorry for such miserable attempts - but perhaps it showcases how little I know of what GridFS can do - maybe someone can clear that up for me in addition to the usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From command line you can use mongofiles: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Tools

```
mongofiles put yourfile.txt
cd /tmp
mongofiles get yourfile.txt
```

The first line puts the file yourfile.txt to the mongodb. The second one retrieves it at another position in the file system.

I think it is not possible to use GridFS directly from the mongo shell.

From python you can use:

```
    class gridfs.GridFS(database, collection='fs')
```

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/gridfs/index.html#gridfs.GridFS

For what GridFS should be used:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/When+to+use+GridFS

Comment: Just to add for anyone as confused as me in the future - mongofiles is an executable that comes in the big 'ol mongo zip you probably downloaded. In windows, open a command window in that directory and from the commandline do this: mongofiles put "C:\path\path\file.txt" with the appropriate info. It stores it in the DB. For proof - DELETE the file you just uploaded, then run this: mongofiles get "C:\path\path\file.txt", same as when you put. That will make the file APPEAR...aka showing us it was stored. Thanks for the answer Frederick!

Answer (score 0):

Insert the file into gridFs from path

`mongofiles -d foorbar -l "D: \ Work \ MongoDB \ GridFS test .txt" put "GridFSTest.txt"`